# Admob import file issue in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I'm integrating admob to my application. I have followed a tutorial from youtube, followed the respective steps but when I tried to run the app it shows me an error message that `GoogleMobileAds/GADAdSize.h' file not found`

I have searched about the error and tried many answers from stack overflow but didn't worked. I have added all the classes and GoogleMobileAds.framework also but this error isn't removing , i'm confused that what the thing i'm missing in this? I have added all the classes from the zip File given in Google Mobile Ads SDK for iOS but still not working how I can resolve this? This is my code for admob,

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"
 GADBannerView *bannerView_;
 //Admob Banner
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50)];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ad unit key";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Now in this import file its showing me this error:

[image: Programme Screen-Shot]

Comment: try with include only framework not all files.And Clean and build agin

Comment: Try including it something like that #import <GoogleMobileAds/GADAdSize.h>

Comment: i have added the framework clean and build but same error. @aBilal17

Comment: added that but same issue. @Yatendra

Comment: @hamza try to add framework using Pod, (pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK')